Is it possible to create a custom MessageBox.Icon in powershell?
I have not found any solution to my problem.
What I don't like is that I'm only able to display the Windows.System.Form::Icons that they provide.
What would be the ultimate solution? Being able to use a locally saved .png File and save it in something like a variable f.e.: $ICON = -File C:PATH\Image.png
and then using $ICON in the code
$MessageIcon = [MessageBoxImage]::$ICON
Here is the code that I've written sofar:
choco upgrade all -y --log-File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log"
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 3010) {
    New-Item -Path C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\rebootnow.txt -Force
}
else {
    return
}
if (Test-Path -Path C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\rebootnow.txt) {
    try {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Exit 2 - Beim Anlegen der Libaries für Windows Forms ist ein Fehler aufgetreten."
        exit 2
    }
    $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
    $MessageboxTitle = "Information"
    $Messageboxbody = "Es wurde im Hintergrund vom IT Administrator ein Update für alle Firmeninternen Apps durchgeführt. Es ist ein Geräte-Neustart nötig um das Update zu finalisieren. Möchten Sie jetzt einen Geräte-Neustart durchführen?"
    $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Information

    try {
        $result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($Messageboxbody, $MessageboxTitle, $ButtonType, $MessageIcon)
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Exit 3 - Beim erstellen der Windows Forms aus den verschiedenen Objekten ist ein Fehler aufgetreten."
        exit 3
    }

    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.MessageBoxResult]::Yes) {
        Remove-Item -Path "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\rebootnow.txt"
        Shutdown.exe /r /t 15
    }
    else {
        return
    }
}
else {
    return
}

The code itself is functional but the problem is the design part. I would like for it to display the company .png so users know its from internal IT Administration.
EDIT2: as to it not being possible to use only powershell to create a custom icon in a Message Box i tried using the Powershell Pro Tool for VSCode that James suggested.
I've created a Windows Forms now and connected it with my script.
Now everything is completly functional and working as intended.
Many thanks to those who participated in helping me with this little project of mine.

The MessageBox class is a wrapper for the Win32 MessageBox function. It's what it is, pre-cooked. If you want a custom presentation, you can build your own specialized window

Thanks for answering my question. So basically its not possible to use any Custom Icons for MessageBoxImage.
What i need to do is build a custom MessageBox from scratch. Is there some documentation where it explains on how to do that?
Best Regards
Philip

Just as a note, I don't think the Chocolatey tag is at all relevant to the question here. That said, you could have a look at the Microsoft Forms docs or, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730941(v=technet.10) - I hate to be that guy but I think this question is answered and you should go search for "building WindowsForms in PowerShell". You could also try tools designed to do this, e.g. PowerShell Pro Tools (https://docs.poshtools.com/powershell-pro-tools-documentation/visual-studio-code/windows-forms-designer)

This C# example might help you get started

Note that MessageBoxImage doesn't represent an image, it's just an enumerator that translates to flags passed to the Win32 function, to select the required functionality. As mentioned, you can find a lot of examples related to building a custom modal window (simply a Form shown calling ShowDialog(), here)

This question is similar to: Custom image enum for MessageBoxResult. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Here's a snippet of the code I use:
#--- Form Drawing References ---

  $Form_Width       =  650 #950    
  $Form_Height      =  275 #605
  $Btn_Height       =   35
  $tabWidth         = $Form_Width-10
  $cboxHeight       =   30
  $cboxWidth        =  200
  $cboxFontSize     =   18
  $tboxHeight       =   30
  $tboxWidth        =  220
  $StdSpacing       =   35
  $CkBoxSpacing     =   10
  $ExitBtnWidth     =   80
  $ExecuteBtnWidth  =  100
  $StatusWidth      =  $Form_Width - 
                       ($ExitBtnWidth+$ExecuteBtnWidth+45)

$IconFile = "$($PSScriptRoot)\ComputerMentor.ico"        
If (-not (Test-Path -Path "$IconFile")){
  $Message = "Error Icon file not found:`n" +
              "$IconFile`n" + 
              "Please copy file to $PSScriptRoot`n" +
              "Default Icon in use!"
  & $StatusMsg
  $JPArgs = @{Path      = "C:\Windows\Installer"
              ChildPath = 
    "{F895A69B-7C3F-49AD-83FC-A87B31EFF8F3}\PowerShellExe.ico"}
  $IconFile = Join-Path @JPArgs
}


 $WindowTitle = "CM's Set MicroSoft Office 365 " +
                "Update Channel - Version: $PGMVers"
  
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
  xmlns =
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x  = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Name = "Window" 
              Title                 = "$WindowTitle" 
              Icon                  = "$IconFile"
              WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
              Width                 = "$Form_Width" 
              Height                = "$Form_Height" 
              FontSize              = "18" 
              Background            = "Blue"
              ShowInTaskbar         = "True">

...

</Window>
"@

$NOArgs = @{TypeName     = 'System.Xml.XmlNodeReader'
            ArgumentList = $xaml}
$reader=(New-Object @NOArgs)

Try  {$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
Catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader." +
                 "`nDouble-check syntax and ensure " +
                 ".net is installed."
     }

$Form.Topmost = $False
$Form.Cursor = [System.Windows.Input.Cursors]::Hand

Fill in your form's objects in place of the ...

